# Decoding ArrayBuffer(5) from COMARK BT42

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, bluetooth, arraybuffer

I am trying to read the temperature from a Comark BT42. The temperature can be retrieved from the device as an arraybuffer. However trying to turn that into a float has some odd results. My app is ionic angular, target device is a Datalogic Memor 10 (Android)

I have the below method

```
pullTemp(id, service, characteristic){
    this.ble.startNotification(id, service, characteristic).subscribe(data => {
      var myArray = new Uint8Array(data[0]);
    var temperatureData = myArray.slice(1,5); // getting bytes 2-5
    var temperature = new Float32Array(new Uint8Array(temperatureData.buffer).reverse().buffer)[0]; // reversing the bytes so as to convert it to little-endian
    console.log(temperature);
      this.readout = temperature + "°C";
  });
  }
```

I get the output "-147578438597117740000" while the reading on the BT42 is "22.5"

Documentation for BT42: https://www.comarkinstruments.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Bluetooth-API-Documentation-20836-3-1.pdf

Comment: can you post the content of `myArray` along with your results?

Comment: [0,224,0,0,255]

Comment: `var temperatureData = myArray.slice(1,5); // getting bytes 2-5
 console.log(temperatureData);`

Output
`Uint8Array(4) [223, 0, 0, 255, buffer: ArrayBuffer(4), byteLength: 4, byteOffset: 0, length: 4, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Uint8Array']`